# “Have you been granted any UK visas in the last 10 years?”

Tags: visas, uk, applications

I was issued Uk student visa in 2009 and i remained in uk till 2012 on student visa. 
Now i am applying for uk visit visa. what should i answer to the question "4 Have you been granted any UK visas in the last 10 years? " 
Technically i was issued visa before 10 years. but i was living in uk till 2012.

Comment: Is this an online application? If so, what happens if you answer ‘Yes’? Eg does the system then ask for the date the visa was issued?

Comment: @Traveller - Although that strategy seems to have worked this time, in general the level of engineering applied to online forms isn't nearly up to the standard where you can rely on that sort of test for anything important.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder not to mention that in recent months, the UK Government's electronic application systems specifically have not accrued a reputation for accuracy and reliability...

Comment: In general this is a **good** thing, BTW. It means that you were approved before, and then left the country. That means it's unfortunate that you have to answer No. But if an officer asks the same question at the airport, do tell the whole story.

Answer (score 52):

The answer is **No**.

You can verify it by answering Yes to the question and entering the year of issue. You will get an alert asking you to enter a date that is in the past 10 years.

I filled one form yesterday and could not enter data from 2009.

[image]

(For the sake of completeness, Month 02 doesn’t make a difference)

They will have your UK travel history, but it would still be advisable to enter the details of that stay in the additional information section, given at the end of the application.

Comment: I'd say one should most definitely add the details in the additional information section. Just in case an overzealous ECO isn't aware that the online form is that strict.